# Formatting output in Java pane

Tags: java, format

I am trying to get the output of a java program to format correctly. The program seems to otherwise work correctly.

[code]

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Exercise4 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double weight;
        double height;
        double bmi;
        String input;

        // Get users's weight.
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your weight.");

        weight = Double.parseDouble(input);

        //Get users's height
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your height in inches.");

        height = Double.parseDouble(input);

        bmi = weight * (703 / Math.pow(height, 2.0));

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your BMI is  " + bmi);


    }

}
```

[/code]

Comment: And what format are you trying to achieve?

Comment: no more than 2 places to the right of the decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, String.format("Your BMI is %1.2f", bmi));
```

`%1.2f` rounds a decimal number to 2 decimal places.

You should take a look at [format specifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html).